# Date comparison logic not working in python pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df which has a column named "PKUP_DTT" and it has dates in the format of DateTime (e.g, 2022-12-31 23:58:00)

Below code tries to see if there is a specific date which is present in the "PKUP_DTT" column, but due to some reasons its not executing the if block even though the condition is true

```
for i,r in df.iterrows():
    if (r['PKUP_DTT'] == '2022-12-31 23:58:00'):
        print("yes")
    else:
        print("No")  


Output : No
Expected Output : yes
```

Comment: Show us the data ?

Comment: Maybe your column is already a datetime/pd.Timestamp type?